# cigarette vs exhaust gas

Tags: air-quality, second-hand-smoke, smoke-inhalation, tobacco

People always associate pollution to cars, but as a frequent biker, I don't really smell anything from exhaust pipes for all 'recent' cars.

When a car passes me, I can always know by the smell if the driver were smoking or not (and I systematically try to hold breath and anticipate that), I can also smell some other odors of the inside of the car, but I don't smell the exhaust pipe gases.

I'm wondering if I'm alone in that case, is it normal? I'm quite paranoiac when it comes to breathing cigarette smoke, so I don't know if it affects only me.

I've searched and posted other threads concerning tobacco smoke, and I'm convinced the amount of tobacco smoke on  a road is not insignificant compared to gas exhaust, of course it's less, but it represents more than 1% (at least here in France) and it's really concentrated when you're in. Smoking tends to generate a lot more particles than people think [1](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn6312-cigarettes-more-polluting-than-diesel-exhaust/), [2](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn6312-cigarettes-more-polluting-than-diesel-exhaust/), and possibly more toxic ones [3](http://oehha.ca.gov/air/chronic_rels/pdf/74908.pdf), [4](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~stephen/reports/bc4927.html), [5](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3084482/)

So is my case 'normal'? Am I alone to smell the cigarette smoke trails in the traffic (on a bike I mean, for those of you that sometimes do bike, I don't think I'd smell them if I were in a car too)? Is it worse to smell those concentrated shot of toxic cigarette smoke or the more dilluted thin particle of exhaust gas?

Comment: What's your actual question? I'm afraid it's not clear to me from what you wrote what exactly you want an answer to.

Comment: Thanks, edited and raised a few questions, I hope one of you can answer some of them

Comment: I doubt this question can be answered since exhaust gas can vary a lot based on many factors (e.g. environment temperature affects diesel emissions, different countries have varying regulations about emissions and different vehicle quality, etc).